# IndexedDB delete record by array key

Tags: typescript, rxjs, indexeddb

I have interesting case when im trying to delete record from IndexedDb with array as key path:

```
remove(storeName: string, key: any) { // key = ['uuid1', 'uuid2']
const open$ = this.open(this.schema.name, this.schema.version);

return mergeMap.call(open$, (db: IDBDatabase) => Observable.create((transactionObserver) => {
  const transaction = db.transaction([storeName], IDB_TRANSACTION_TYPE.READWRITE);
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
  const getRequest = objectStore.delete(key);

  const onTransactionError = (err) => { transactionObserver.error(err); };
  const onTransactionComplete = () => {};
  const onRecordDelete = (event: any) => { // eslint-disable-line
    transactionObserver.next();
    transactionObserver.complete();
  };

  transaction.addEventListener(IDB_EVENT.COMPLETE, onTransactionComplete);
  transaction.addEventListener(IDB_EVENT.ERROR, onTransactionError);
  getRequest.addEventListener(IDB_EVENT.SUCCESS, onRecordDelete);

  return () => {
    getRequest.removeEventListener(IDB_EVENT.SUCCESS, onRecordDelete);
    getRequest.removeEventListener(IDB_EVENT.ERROR, onTransactionError);
    transaction.removeEventListener(IDB_EVENT.COMPLETE, onTransactionComplete);
  };
}));
```

}

Delete method and transaction returns no errors and status is "Done" but storeObject value is still there.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why did you tag this as `javascript` when this is not javascript?

Comment: This is `javascript` and RxJs.

Comment: Please do not tag code that is not javascript as javascript. This is clearly not javascript.